# What Scipy modules are actually calls to Numpy ones?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am confused by the fact that some modules in Scipy are not actually part of the library but are rather calls to modules in Numpy.

One example for all is `linalg`:

```
import scipy
scipy.linalg
```

this gives

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'linalg'

on the flip side, the right way to call it from Scipy is

```
from scipy import linalg
scipy.linalg
```

which must be a handle for

```
numpy.linalg
```

How does this work? And technically what distinguishes Numpy and Scipy then?

Comment: Have a look at [`scipy/__init__.py`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/__init__.py) - some of the import magic it does is [documented there](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/__init__.py#L15-L16), and there actually seems to be [some particular magic regarding `linalg`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/__init__.py#L78-L82).

Comment: @LukasGraf Thanks! So the needed explicit import is because of name conflict with the Numpy ones?

Comment: @martina: No, you'll need to explicitly import the ones that don't conflict too.

Comment: No, I don't think that's the reason for it. The name conflict basically arises because `scipy/__init__.py` does `from numpy import *`, but that is later undone for linalg by `del linalg` and `__all__.remove('linalg')`. I can't tell you the exact reason why scipy seems to require explicit import for its submodules, but it seems to apply to most of them.

Answer (score 3):

> the right way to call it from Scipy is
>
> ```
> from scipy import linalg
> scipy.linalg
> ```
>
> which must be a handle for
>
> ```
> numpy.linalg
> ```

Nope! They're totally different modules. Also, it'd be either `import scipy.linalg` and then use `scipy.linalg`, or `from scipy import linalg` and then use `linalg`.

If you want to tell whether a SciPy module is actually from NumPy, the easiest way is to just look at it interactively:

```
In [9]: scipy.random
Out[9]: <module 'numpy.random' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/random/__init__.pyc'>

In [10]: scipy.linalg
Out[10]: <module 'scipy.linalg' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/linalg/__init__.pyc'>
```

As you can see, the one from `numpy` says `numpy` in the output. This is an IPython session, but a regular Python interactive session will say something similar.

Comment: Where are they different? Also, why then my first lines of code return that error? Normally if you import the full library you access the modules like that.

Comment: @martina: They're different in far too many ways to list. Also, the way you've been doing things is *not* the normal way to access a package's submodules. You should always import submodules explicitly. NumPy just imports most of its own submodules automatically as a convenience. If you have more questions, post a new question rather than asking in the comments.